# Pass variables from custom server to components in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have set up a custom server in NextJS as illustrated [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) for custom routing.

**server.js:**

```
app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

      if (foreignLang(pathname, lang)) {
        app.render(req, res, checkLangAndConvert(links, pageVal, pathname, lang), query)
      } else {
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    })
      .listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
      })
  })
```

it basically maps `/en/url` to `/another_url` for i18n.

I understand I can use `query` parameter here and read it in the component, but I would like to pass options to the `App` without rechecking the URL. Is it possible to pass options from server level to app level without reading the URL?

**Edit:** After a bit of investigating the marked answer explained that `query` actually does not mean query-paramter in the URL, rather than passing a value from the server to client. Misleading word as it indicates only client side action. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of [custom-server-express](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/custom-server-express/) where they pass `id` [from server to client side](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/custom-server-express/server.js#L21-L23)

So in your case it will be something like this

**server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === '/pl/index') {
      app.render(req, res, '/index', { ...query, lang: 'pl' });
    } else if (pathname === '/en/index') {
      app.render(req, res, '/index', { ...query, lang: 'en' });
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

function IndexPage(props) {
  return <h1>index lang: {props.router.query.lang}</h1>;
}

export default withRouter(IndexPage);
```

Going to `/pl/index` will render `index lang: pl` and

going to `/en/index` will render `index lang: en` accordingly

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man, I just realised I have fixed it myself. The problem is that `query` is a bit misleading as it indicates that it is an URL query, but actually it is just the name of passing data forward from the server to initalProps. So I actually solved it. :)

Comment: agree, it was confusing for me at first as well

Comment: So just one additional question here, although I have solved the issue I'd like to ask what `withRouter` does here. Is it the replacement for getting `getInitialProps` from the server? I don't use `withRouter` at all and it still works just fine with `getInitialProps` for a custom `_app`. Intrigued to know.

Comment: [withRouter](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#using-a-higher-order-component) is a higher order component that injects `router` into any component. I think both ways are fine. The main difference that `getInitialProps` will initially get executed on server.

Comment: the only difference that `getInitialProps` [can not be used in children components](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle). So if you want to access `router` inside lets say `Nav` component the only option to go is to use `withRouter`.

Comment: Yes correct, I can pass them as props though :) so in your example query is actually not related to a query parameter either? The word 'router' seems misleading too here.

Comment: yes, I think that's how nextjs handles params from server, they just pack them into "router".

Comment: I'm learning nextjs as well so might be wrong somewhere :D but that's how I understand it so far.

Comment: Don't use params as a word here. Just say "variables"? Because that's my point what I wanted to do. I wanted to pass variables from the server to the view but NOT via query parameter like (`?example=this`)

Comment: yes variables that you pass from server ends up on query params of the router without being a part of the query itself. So this [example from the official docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/custom-server-express/server.js#L21-L23) I mean `/posts/99` will show the same UI as `/posts?id=99` it means that UI code does not really care if it is a variable from server or a query param as it will be taken from `router.query` anyway

Comment: Ahh very good! Things would have been more convenient with your answer than as currently I'm passing props down to each component. Going to accept this for now, but will test in the future :)

Comment: seems that nextjs does not support it out of the box. See these threads https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3292 and https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1245

Comment: Thanks but how do I require multiple files then to map through them... it doesn't answer it there.

Comment: what do you want to do with the files? :)

Comment: I want to import them to render. So imagine they're images but I don't know their file names and how many there are... I wanna do something like `images = path/to/img/folder` and then `images.map=>`

Comment: that's a good use case but unfortunately I dont know how to do that :(

Comment: The example [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js) has been updated and this solution does not seem to be working sadly.