# How can i pass an object from node to next js component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Exploring server side rendering with nodejs express and next, I have an application previously running on node and react and I'm trying to implement only one route with server side rendering using next js. I was wondering what is the best way of implementing server-side rendering, I see I can get an object from database in node and pass it as a query parameter to the component but not sure if this is the best way, any suggestions?

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

    server.get('/event/:id', (req, res) => {
        const actualPage = '/event';
        const event = db.getEvent(req.params.id)
        const queryParams = {event: event} <--------------------- IS THIS REASONABLE?
        return next.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })

    server.get('/_next/*', (request, response) => {
        console.log('request url:', request.url)
        return handle(request, response)
    })

    server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './web/build')))
    server.get('*', (request, response) => {
        response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './web/build/index.html'))
    })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
     console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
   })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

pages/events.js

```
export default class extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps(init) {
        init.query.event; // this contains my object
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `getInitialProps` should **return**

Comment: look at this answer, this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642345/pass-variables-from-custom-server-to-components-in-nextjs

Comment: @cal_br_mar fantastic! thank you!